# Are "moustache" distortions in rectilinear ultrawides the result of a fisheye+pincushion construction?

Tags: lens-design, fisheye

If I wanted to try and build an ultrawide, I guess I would try building a fisheye first, then try tearing the frame back into shape with a group that introduces pincushion distortion.

The kind of "wavy" distortions found in some ultrawides seem very similar to what you would get as remaining distortion if you actually did that....

Is this how some of these lenses actually work, or is this a coincidence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how lenses create "moustache" distortion without any intent to apply that knowledge to an actual photographic problem or even any indication that there is any intent to create photographs.

Comment: How is understanding of photographic equipment design off topic?

Comment: ...given this whole site runs on "because", and discussing equipment design tends to add some "because" back into the "because" supply.....

Comment: It's not off topic *if there is a specific photographic purpose involved* (i.e. solving a problem related to actually taking a photo). This question demonstrates no intent in that direction whatsoever. The question needs to be improved to include what photographic problem you are attempting to solve. As it stands now, this question is along the lines of, "Here's my theory about how this works. Am I right?" But it doesn't attempt to remotely say why or how your theory will lead to actually taking a specific photo.

Comment: vtc b/c "Questions" of the form *"[hypothesis] Is that right?"* aren't real questions.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29), it's not quite as simple as barrel + pincusion = moustache. You might be able to approximate moustache with a combination, but it's not quite the same.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you might be talking about anamorphic lenses. They stretch the image, so more of the sensor is used to capture the image, resulting in sharper, better looking results (anamorphic lenses usually cost around 40k$ tho).
In post, you need to rescale the footage, so "unstretch" it so to say. What actually happens is that the pixel aspect-ratio (PAR) gets changed, from squared pixels to something around 1.33:1. Thus, any bokeh (the spots of light coming from sources out of focus) gets squeezed down as well. This results in what I believe you call "moustache distortions", because the bokeh will look like a strip rather than a round halo.

Comment: No, the question is about flaws in wideangle lenses that turn straight lines into wavy lines.

Comment: Well in that case, this is called "lense-distortion" and doesn't only happen with wideangle lenses. It happens to every lense; even a 200mm lense will have some lense-distortion. Read up how lenses work and how they treat light to find out more, it's a lot to put in a comment.

Comment: The whole question is about a specific case of such distortion...